# How to Import FirebaseAuthentication.net into a xamarin.forms project

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, .net-standard

I'm relatively new to xamarin and have been trying to get this library to work with a Xamarin.Forms project ; https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet

I have tried everything I could think of all to no avail. any help would really be appreciated.
What I have tried so far.
Made a .net standard(1.4) shared project and tried referencing this library from it. When this did not work I downloaded the source code and then referenced that, that seemed to work till I tried making a build which said that the newtonsoft.json library it referenced did not contain a reference to monotouch.droid .
I feel like I am missing something simple, to make it work.